# Illegal instruction (core dumped) error while building Android 11

Tags: python, java, compiling, android

For a quiet some time I'm trying to build Android 11 for Sony Xperia XZ2 H8266. Everytime process comes to build org.apache.http.legacy package it gets an error.

```
[ 99% 263/264] //external/apache-http:org.apache.http.legacy dexpreopt [common]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/external/apache-http/org.apache.http.legacy/and
roid_common/dexpreopt/profile.prof
ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="*:e" out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/profman --create-profile-fro
m=external/apache-http/art-profile --apk=out/soong/.intermediates/external/apach
e-http/org.apache.http.legacy/android_common/aligned/org.apache.http.legacy.jar 
--dex-location=/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --reference-profile-
file=out/soong/.intermediates/external/apache-http/org.apache.http.legacy/androi
d_common/dexpreopt/profile.prof
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
18:31:01 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I'm using old PowerEdge 2950 with 2 quad-core Xeon CPUs with 32 Gb RAM running with Ubuntu 20.04. I've read that org.apache.http.legacy is deprecated package. I would appreciate same hint where to look for the core of the problem.

Thanks in advance. DoomRider

Comment: I'd ask at SO itself, not in a community that concentrates on the Ubuntu  OS. You are welcome here, but I would think that other forums are better suited.

Comment: Apparently the application that gets ran as part of the building process has been compiled with some instruction that isn't supported by your CPU. You may get more info if your run the app along with all command line parameters copied from the `ninja` output under a gdb. Then once crash happens, you'll bail out into gdb, and you can look around to see what exactly instruction it's trying to execute, and then google up what instruction set it should be part of. As for workarounds: perhaps only building/installing the app in question yourself, before continuing to build Android.